# Json Schema Data Set for validation testing

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have been looking for a good sample data set of json schemas and corresponding valid and invalid json instances.

I have only found a few test sets in some github projects:

https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema/tree/master/json_schema_test_suite

https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator

However the data sets are pretty simple and do not cover all cases.

Does anyone know any good repository with this kind of data set?

Comment: Uh, you haven't really looked in depth; my implementation (your second link) is very heavily tested. But I test keywords individually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official test suite is: https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema-test-suite

Those tests should cover all features (draft v3 and v4), including optional features.

Comment: I am marking it as the right answer as it is the most complete I could find. 
However I think it is missing some more complex schemas with multiple keyword interactions. 
What do you mean with "official"? I would like to contribute with more complete test case but it would be nice to do it on a widely accepted test set. 
I have posted a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847063/what-is-the-logical-relationship-between-keyword-in-a-json-schema), that is something not covered in the test set.
Thank you!

Comment: Official as in, the authors of the spec (myself included) have declared the tests to be correct, and it's included in the `json-schema` GitHub organisation.  We encourage people to test against it when developing validators.

Comment: If there are tests you feel are missing, then pull requests are welcome!

Comment: In reply to the "missing more complex schemas with multiple keyword interactions" comment: With JSON Schema, each validation keyword adds a constraint to validation, which means that each can be tested individually. As above, if you think any interactions are missing, log an issue or pull request! =]