# What is equivalent to multiple types in OpenAPI 3.1? anyOf or oneOf?

Tags: jsonschema, openapi, openapi-generator, json-schema-validator

I want to change multiple types (supported in the latest drafts of JSON Schema so does OpenAPI v3.1) to `anyOf`, `oneOf` but I am a bit confused to which the types would be mapped to. Or can I map to any of the two.

PS. I do have knowledge about `anyOf`, `oneOf`, etc. but multiple types behavior is a little ambiguous. (I know the schema is invalid but it is just an example that is more focused towards type conversion)

```json
{
    "type": ["null", "object", "integer", "string"],
    "properties": {
        "prop1": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "prop2": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "enum": [2, 3, 4, 5],
    "const": "sample const entry",
    "exclusiveMinimum": 1.22,
    "exclusiveMaximum": 50,
    "maxLength": 10,
    "minLength": 2,
    "format": "int32"
}
```

I am converting it this way.

```json
{
    "anyOf": [{
            "type": "null"
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "prop1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "prop2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "integer",
            "enum": [2, 3, 4, 5],
            "exclusiveMinimum": 1.22,
            "exclusiveMaximum": 50,
            "format": "int32"
        },
        {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 10,
            "minLength": 2,
            "const": "sample const entry"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your example is not valid:

1. The initial schema doesn't match anything, it's an "impossible" schema. The `"enum": [2, 3, 4, 5]` and `"const": "sample const entry"` constraints are mutually exclusive, and so are `"const": "sample const entry"` and `"maxLength": 10`.
2. The rewritten schema is not equivalent to the original schema because the `enum` and `const` were moved from the root level into subschemas. Yes, this way the schema makes more sense and will sort of work (e.g. it will match the specified numbers - but not strings! because of `const` vs `maxLength` contradiction), but it's not the same the original schema.

---

With regard to `oneOf`/`anyOf`:

**It depends.**

The choice between `anyOf` and `oneOf` depends on the context, i.e. whether an instance is can match *more than one* subschema or *exactly one* subschema. In other words, whether multiple subschema match is considered OK or an error. [Nullable references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114924/113116) typically need `anyOf` rather than `oneOf`, but other cases vary from schema to schema.

For example,

```yaml
"type": ["number", "integer"]
```

corresponds to `anyOf` because there's an overlap - integer values are also valid "number" values in JSON Schema.

Whereas

```yaml
"type": ["string", "integer"]
```

can be represented using either `oneOf` or `anyOf`. `oneOf` is semantically closer since strings and integers are totally different data types with no overlap. But technically `anyOf` also works, it's just there won't be more than one subschema match in this particular case.

In your example, all base `type` values are distinct with no overlap, so I would use `oneOf`, but technically `anyOf` will also work.

Comment: Thanks @Helen for this detailed answer. But as you stated above that enum and const are mutually exclusive to each other, this does not make sense because enum and cost are of different types not the same. In other words if i need to add const (for string type schema) and enums (for integer or number type schema) using multiple types approach how can I do that?

Comment: Having both `const` and `enum` in the same schema does not make sense because `const` is a just syntactic sugar for an enum with only one element. That is, `"const": "sample const entry"` is the same as `"enum": ["sample const entry"]`.

Comment: In general, `const` and `enum` can be used with [_any_ data types](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1) - not just primitives (string, number, integer, boolean, null) but also arrays and objects. Note that these JSON Schema keywords are evaluated [in isolation from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27847063/113116) and regardless of the type of the instance/value being validated against the schema. Your example is an impossible schema because nothing can match both `"const": "sample const entry"` and `"enum": [2, 3, 4, 5]` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`anyOf` gives you a closer match for the semantics than `oneOf`;

The problem (or benefit!) of `oneOf` is that it will fail if you happen to match 2 different cases.

That is unlikely to be what you want, given the source of your conversion which has those looser semantics.

Imagine converting `["integer","number"]`, for example; if the input was a `1`, you'd match both and fail using `oneOf`.

Comment: (And as someone has pointed out below - your actual schema in the example is not useful anyway!)